# Salesforce, LWC lightning-input type="time" weird behavior in Mobile View

Tags: salesforce, timepicker, salesforce-lightning, lwc, salesforce-communities

I am using, LWC lighting input type time tag, like below

```
<lightning-input type="time" name="input4" label="Required Time field" required
                         value="18:30:00.000Z"></lightning-input>
```

But Selection of Time in Mobile view showing me Seconds and Milliseconds along with Hours and Minutes.

Please let me know how can I hide Seconds and Milliseconds from Mobile View.
Attached is the Screenshot of the Mobile View Time Selection.

[Attached Mobile View Time Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUGQ3.png)

Comment: This is probably linked to other issues with Time fields (on Desktops), which are quite buggy in LWC. We had to circumvent our issues and recreate a custom field. But, have you tried using the 'size' attribute of lightning-input, just in case ?

Comment: PS: have you removed the aria-* and role attributes, as suggested in the doc ? https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/timepicker/